# Using manually built opencv with other versions of python

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-18.04, dependency-management, nvidia-jetson-nano

Using a jetson nano with jetpack 4.5.1 requires me to manually install opencv since the included version comes with version 4.1.1 and in order to utilize CUDA and subsequently, YOLOv5, requires 4.1.2 or later. I manually built opencv following [this](https://qengineering.eu/install-opencv-4.5-on-jetson-nano.html) guide.

Currently opencv works on python3.6, but my question is how do I use my built opencv on other versions of python (specifically 3.8, which is supported).

Thanks in advance